join Firestore Database query results
I am working on a news app in Clutter with firebase databas. I have a collections " news" with seperate document for each news entity and in that another collection "comments" for the user comments
Im the comments collection I am storing only message,timestamp and uuid of the user who commented. But at the time of retrieving this comments collection I want to pick the "username" and "profilepic" values from "users" collection by matching uuid . Please help mw
Tried by getting the comments collection first and then fetching the users collection at the time of display ,but getting error as I am using the async functions inside build context

Instead of describing what your database looks like, please edit your question and add a screenshot of it. Please also explain in detail what exactly would  you like to get.
